# Restore values of session variable of previous page and forward page if user clicks on browser back & forward arrow respectively

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am using the same session variables in my .Net MVC project that are getting updated whenever an action result is called. But if I am clicking the browser back button, the previous values are not getting restored, keeps updated ids in session variables and hence page doesn't load any data.

Is there any way to catch it on the controller in the list or something to load values of that particular view each time user visits there, without using ajax?
Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Session object is made so that data stored in it persists across HTTP requests. So it sounds like its doing exactly what its supposed to do. If the action sets a value to an existing key then it will store that value. One of the  purposes of using the Session State is to store values that will be needed across HTTP requests.

If you need a specific value for a particular view and you want to use Session State I would suggest creating a specific key that is only accessed when needed. In your case for that View.

Comment: Thanks alot for this information but I am stuck if I have all different views to get loaded. For example: I have Introduction, story views. Problem is occuring when I have more than 1 story type of content then the same story view will be loaded but with different id. On run time how to find out which story is user going to click on and create session variable for that.

Comment: Hey, I don't know if I am understanding correctly. But it sounds like a particular Story is being displayed depending on user selection. Is that a drop down? A button? An upload? Irregardless, each story should have some kind of ID in which case when the form is submitted the ID should be sent back to the controller, and that's where you can set your Session variable as well.